# How could I make an extension that open a url when the icon is clicked?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

There will be an icon in Chrome's extension bar, I'd like to open a link in a new tab when the icon is clicked(instead of popup a popup page). How could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your background page:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  chrome.tabs.create({url: "http://www.google.com"});
});
```

Google documentation for

- [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked)
- [`chrome.tabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create)